# Transferring Jmeter reports from Ubuntu environment to local windows machine

Tags: jmeter

I executed the jmx file from ubuntu environment on amazon server. It got executed and report files are also generated. But i want to transfer/move these reports to my windows local. I dont want to use winscp/filezilla, as my data is very huge for huge threads(i tried this, but its taking hell lot of time to push).

Pls suggest a way to do it.

Comment: How big are the files? FTP should do the job. Are you working with a free instance? If so, then the latency is expected.

Comment: its more than 60MB... i am running scripts for 300 threads for  more than 30 mins duration.

Comment: If you are moving .jtl files, a gzip on the remote system can reduce the size up to 90%.
The standard reports/graphs  can be easily rebuilt locally, if you have the same script file.

Comment: Sure. Let me give a try with this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use some form of JMeter Plugin which will upload your test results into Cloud Analysis services. Amazon instances usually have good bandwidth so it shouldn't take long. If you need results locally you can download them from services, usually they provide possibility to fetch compressed results files. As a bonus you'll get advanced analysis toolkit.

Currently I'm aware of the following plugins:

- [Loadosophia.org Uploader](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/LoadosophiaUploader/)
- [BlazeMeter's Plug-in for JMeter](http://blazemeter.com/blazemeters-plug-jmeter)

Both are free and easy to install/use.